# Is it possible to check if anyone has a certain browser link open and if not execute a function?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am making a web app that involves the creation of several rooms (users create them). These rooms are then stored on an array on the server. Using react router each of these rooms are given their own unique url /roomCodeGoesHere. I want to periodically check the rooms to see if anyone is in it(I guess in this case has the browser open?) and if there is no one in it, to have the room be deleted from the array.

Is there any way I can go about doing this? (the only ways I can think of seem hacky and are probably not good practice)

Comment: Send a request to your server every few seconds, if you don’t receive any request in X amount of time, delete the room

Comment: Is there a specific method that I can use to check for the request that other than an infinite loop? I tried searching but can't find any specific results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor the user count within your server array (via put request or websocket on mount/unmount), and if the room empties conditionally delete it within the controller. A room should by default start with 1 occupancy since it needs a creator. If you don't want to delete the room right away, then do the same thing but create a setTimeout that conditionally clears itself unless someone new enters.

This chat app I made deletes a room at 0 users using the above method:
http://astral-chat-app.herokuapp.com/